# How to tell which nixpkgs are being used to build a derivation?

Tags: nix

I’m trying to figure out why [I can’t get `nix-build` to produce the expected output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/719283/3645). Is there some way to check which nixpkgs versions are being used to build a derivation? Something like `nix-build --verbose` to just at some point print the nixpkgs hash.

For a use case, consider `{pkgs ? import ./nixpkgs.nix}`. How do you *know* whether *something* is providing a `pkgs` parameter to this derivation? If the derivation ended up being built with the current OS nixpkgs, then something must've provided a `pkgs` parameter. If it was built with the nixpkgs defined in `nixpkgs.nix` then it was *not* provided. Figuring out which of these were the case would be very tedious to do manually:

1. Look through all the dependencies of the derivation coming from nixpkgs
2. For each dependency, check whether it has a different hash in the OS and `nixpkgs.nix` versions of nixpkgs
3. If the hash is different, check which nixpkgs it came from and conclude that that nixpkgs was used
4. If the hash is the same, continue

Of course, it's possible that it doesn't matter, in case all dependency hashes are the same in both nixpkgs versions, but it would at least be nice to be able to resolve this without a lot of manual work.

[Off-site dupe](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-tell-which-nixpkgs-was-used-to-build-a-result/22101).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking which `nixpkgs` is using `nix-build` is maybe not really well defined since `nixpkgs` is just a variable like any other variable (that may get it's value from an url, a local file, a channel, a simple attribute set). Actually, you could even have multiple instances of nixpkgs in the same repository. You can find the nixpkgs version using different methods:

**Method 1**: if you know from which channel nixpkgs is coming from (say `<nixpkgs>`) and you just want to check which commit is your channel pointing to:

```
$ nix-instantiate --eval -E '(import <nixpkgs> {}).lib.version'
"22.11pre405560.2da64a81275"
```

(note that the last number is the commit of nixpkgs, and you could use `nix eval` in place of `nix-instantiate` but the interface is not really stable as far as I know)

You can also get the path using

```
$ nix-instantiate --eval -E '(import <nixpkgs> {}).path'
/nix/store/p5jayhh78vbq7kpw6p3m1s61g365zwam-nixos/nixos
```

**Method 2**: For more complicated derivations where you are not even sure where `nixpkgs` is defined, you can debug it like any other variable using `buildins.trace`:

To give a more precise example, let's say your file is:

```
{
  pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}
}:
pkgs.hello
```

then you can check the value of pkgs using:

```
{
  pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}
}:
builtins.trace (pkgs.lib.version) pkgs.hello
```

When you compile you get this, where the commit of nixpkgs is `2da64a81275`:

```
$ nix-build a.nix
trace: 22.11pre405560.2da64a81275
/nix/store/y4mxrg8c6l09lb2szl69vwl4f6441i5k-hello-2.12.1
```

For more debug functions see [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/lib/debug.nix).

PS: don't forget that nix is a lazy language and only evaluates what is needed. So if a variable is not used, trace on this variable will not be called

```
$ cat a.nix
{
  pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}
}:
let
  x = builtins.trace (pkgs.lib.version) 2; # <-- never needed
in
pkgs.hello
$ nix-build a.nix
/nix/store/y4mxrg8c6l09lb2szl69vwl4f6441i5k-hello-2.12.1
```

**Method 3**: if you want to know all the dependencies of a derivation and do not care about the nixpkgs's version (after all maybe the derivation is internally calling a given `nixpkgs` and then override its inputs):

```
$ nix show-derivation $(nix-instantiate default.nix) 
{
  "/nix/store/g6qkwa2xaq6i40cwl9bpjxi19m7q8121-hello-2.12.1.drv": {
    "outputs": {
      "out": {
        "path": "/nix/store/y4mxrg8c6l09lb2szl69vwl4f6441i5k-hello-2.12.1"
      }
    },
    "inputSrcs": [
      "/nix/store/9krlzvny65gdc8s7kpb6lkx8cd02c25b-default-builder.sh"
    ],
    "inputDrvs": {
      "/nix/store/0na7ivzsc073j4kpn9kqnvd2zvwb8g0a-hello-2.12.1.tar.gz.drv": [
        "out"
      ],
      "/nix/store/1av43alhcb8a894sz2cnnf9aldfdyb0h-stdenv-linux.drv": [
        "out"
      ],
      "/nix/store/6pj63b323pn53gpw3l5kdh1rly55aj15-bash-5.1-p16.drv": [
        "out"
      ]
    },
    "system": "x86_64-linux",
    "builder": "/nix/store/1b9p07z77phvv2hf6gm9f28syp39f1ag-bash-5.1-p16/bin/bash",
    "args": [
      "-e",
      "/nix/store/9krlzvny65gdc8s7kpb6lkx8cd02c25b-default-builder.sh"
    ],
    "env": {
      "buildInputs": "",
      "builder": "/nix/store/1b9p07z77phvv2hf6gm9f28syp39f1ag-bash-5.1-p16/bin/bash",
      "cmakeFlags": "",
      "configureFlags": "",
      "depsBuildBuild": "",
      "depsBuildBuildPropagated": "",
      "depsBuildTarget": "",
      "depsBuildTargetPropagated": "",
      "depsHostHost": "",
      "depsHostHostPropagated": "",
      "depsTargetTarget": "",
      "depsTargetTargetPropagated": "",
      "doCheck": "1",
      "doInstallCheck": "",
      "mesonFlags": "",
      "name": "hello-2.12.1",
      "nativeBuildInputs": "",
      "out": "/nix/store/y4mxrg8c6l09lb2szl69vwl4f6441i5k-hello-2.12.1",
      "outputs": "out",
      "patches": "",
      "pname": "hello",
      "propagatedBuildInputs": "",
      "propagatedNativeBuildInputs": "",
      "src": "/nix/store/pa10z4ngm0g83kx9mssrqzz30s84vq7k-hello-2.12.1.tar.gz",
      "stdenv": "/nix/store/bj5n3k01mq8bysw0rcdm7jxvhc620pd3-stdenv-linux",
      "strictDeps": "",
      "system": "x86_64-linux",
      "version": "2.12.1"
    }
  }
}
```

**Other debugging tools**
Note that for debugging you may also want to read the source of the derivation, enter into `nix-shell` to run the phases manually and/or using various tools following the spirit of `builtins.trace` (see [this discussion](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/debug-a-nix-expression-with-debug-trace-statements/691) for instance).