# How to use the new `pythonOutputDistHook` in nixpkgs?

Tags: nix

I've tried a bunch of things to get my project to [create a `result-dist` folder with a wheel I can publish to PyPI](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/why-is-buildpythonpackage-passthru-not-in-my-result-folder/21852). Somehow, even though I'm using a nixpkgs version with [`pythonOutputDistHook`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/190487) in it, I only ever get a `result` folder, not a `result-dist` folder.

My investigation so far:

1. `pythonOutputDistHook` is optional based on `withDistOutput`.
2. `withDistOutput` is true if `format` contains one of `["pyproject" "setuptools" "flit"]`.
3. `format ? "setuptools"` and my code doesn't set `format`, so `pythonOutputDistHook` should be included.
4. I've verified that `pythonOutputDistHook` is in [my nixpkgs](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/vcard/-/merge_requests/196/diffs?diff_id=497160117#81b77de645410ddd33e10b09f92bd009c476ff84_7_5):

   ```
   $ cd nixpkgs
   $ git checkout 9c14978f845f33b152f722709caf42148580a30c
   HEAD is now at 9c14978f845 Merge master into staging-next
   $ git grep pythonOutputDistHook
   pkgs/development/interpreters/python/hooks/default.nix:  pythonOutputDistHook = callPackage ({ }:
   pkgs/development/interpreters/python/mk-python-derivation.nix:, pythonOutputDistHook
   pkgs/development/interpreters/python/mk-python-derivation.nix:      pythonOutputDistHook
   pkgs/top-level/python-packages.nix:    pythonOutputDistHook
   ```

Could something be injecting a different `pkgs` argument into one of the Nix files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard builder in Nixpkgs (`stdenv.mkDerivation`) can create multiple outputs. Some typical outputs are the default output `out` but also `lib`, `bin`, `dev` and `doc`. Any derivation can specify which outputs it creates. Outputs can be referred to directly:

```
$ nix-build -A bash.dev
/nix/store/pji7665awsg1fcp2irhnfm3508lvsgh0-bash-5.1-p16-dev
```

Since recently, `buildPythonPackage` (which calls `stdenv.mkDerivation` behind the scenes), creates a `dist` output that contains artifacts for distribution, specifically, wheels:

```
$ find $(nix-build -A python3.pkgs.pytest.dist)
/nix/store/flg6ahbbmppq5vpjcxdhzs9fz7dx86vq-python3.10-pytest-7.1.3-dist
/nix/store/flg6ahbbmppq5vpjcxdhzs9fz7dx86vq-python3.10-pytest-7.1.3-dist/pytest-7.1.3-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: Basically, `nix-build -A dist` does the trick.